# Environment Specific Options Token

Tags: plugins, options

Is it possible to add a token to any wp-option that could be replaced on get where the token being defined in a plugin’s option or the configure file?

```
E.g. 
http://[[[env_token]]].sitename.com/some-page.html => 
http://staging.sitename.com/some-page.html or 
http://dev.sitename/some-page.html or 
http://www.sitename.com
```

To be more specific I am managing a Wordpress instance inside a development life cycle where I often copy production data down to staging and development servers.  Often the options tables are unmanageable and have changed since the last dump.  However, after analyzing what the most frequent changes are between servers I noticed it is the environmental specific tokens like dev and staging.

I am a little concerned with running a string replace on every option get, but I am making use of page, data, and object caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [filter reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Blog_Information_and_Option_Filters) on the codex. In particular, note that you can use the form `option_$foo` to filter just a specific option key. So if you wanted a filter specific to the `siteurl` option, you could do:

```
add_filter( 'option_siteurl', 'my_url_filter' );
```

Comment: Additionally, the filter 'pre_option_' . $option exists. E.g. pre_option_siteurl